# How to get functional again after "you must re-authorize the OAuth Application `GitHub for VSCode`"

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

So one fine day, I get an error message, trying to push to a remote repo:
[image: SAML SSO Error box]

and in the Git Log can be found:

```
remote: The `<redacted>' organization has enabled or enforced SAML SSO. To access
remote: this repository, you must re-authorize the OAuth Application `GitHub for VSCode`.
```

## Attempt #1: Search result

Search results for `GitHub for VSCode` point to: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/github which prompts to install/authorise a new extension: GitHub PRs and Issues (??)

I try, it adds a new extension, I authorize it, but still no joy trying to Push/Pull from remote!

## Attempt #2: Logout

(GH PRs/Issues is still installed)

Then I try signing out (based on a SO answer for a similar `SAML SSO` error)

[image: GitHub Sign Out - menu option]

...but how do I sign back in now!? [My current window] already has repos linked, so the options below are missing:

[image: Clone repo dialogs]

Answer: new window... duh!

Login - still no joy ‍♂️

## Attempt #3: de-/re-authorize from GH UI

1. [top-right] Profile button -> Settings -> [Left menu] Applications -> [top-bar] Authorized OAuth Apps
2. Scroll to `GitHub for VSCode` and click `...` -> `revoke`
3. Repeat log-in process from attempt #2
4. Try to push: NEW ERROR! (Success! - well sort of...)

## New Error

Next it complained about my credential.manager, which I had borked by trying commands from another SO post:

```
git config --global credential.helper <something I don't have>
```

Which I was able to recover by repeating the above command, re-using the `credential.helper` that I *do* have, from the key/value in `git config -l`.

## Attempt #4: Permutations (?)

- Re-revoke from GH UI (link in attempt #3)
- Re-login via new window + `Clone Repository`

  - Re-using an old, empty window will complain `Error:Bad Credential` instead of restarting OAuth...
- Nope...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOOOOO it was a Code-18; and the crux lies in the OAuth flow screens.

THE FINAL Steps:

1. Revoke authorization from GH UI (like in attempt #3)
2. Sign out from VSCode UI + re-login via `Clone a Repository` (like in Attempt #2)
3. PAY CLOSE ATTENTION TO THE OAUTH FLOW:
   [image: Begin OAuth flow]
   [image]

... Unfortunately I wasn't able to repro the critical screen (!?), but basically, it presented a list with:

- a single item: `my org-name`, alongside a green `Authorize` button
- *another* green `Authorize` button outside/under the list (possibly next to a `refuse` button)

This is what that screen looks like as of 2024-02:
[image: Make sure each organization is "Authorized"]

NOTE: the text on the buttons is IIRC, since I wasn't able to get back to that exact screen...?

## **The key was to click on the `Authorize` *beside* the org-name**, and *NOT* the one under the whole list, which I had been using to date

... time to get back to pushing commits!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a note to this because it stumped me.

Not sure exactly what causes it, but if you're running VS Code and also have your git account authorized through **Visual Studio**, you may have to revoke access to Visual Studio and reauthorize it to continue using git from your VS Code terminal.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I signed out from VScode. Deleted my local repo, and cloned from Github to my local repo again. I did not revoke the access.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue while starting my codespace from VS Code.
I solved it by **launching my codespace from GitHub web**.
[image: Select Open in Visual Studio Code]